# session_regenerate_id doesnt work together with sesion_destroy

Tags: php, session

I found session_regenerate_id will not work it together with session_destroy(), please see
this one works

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $old='old is: '.session_id();
   session_regenerate_id(true);
   echo $old;
   echo '<br>';
   echo 'new is: '.session_id();     
?>
```

this one failed, return 2 same session id numbers

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $old='old is: '.session_id();
   session_regenerate_id(true);
   session_destroy();
   session_unset();
   session_start();
   echo $old;
   echo '<br>';
   echo 'new is: '.session_id();     
?>
```

I use php 5.3.3, the second one is a recommended method to produce a new session, but why it does not work on my side.

thanks everyone,after tests, I found session_destroy must be invoked before session_regenerate_id(), or session_regenerate_id never works.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['abc']=12323;
$old='old is: '.session_id();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);
echo $old;
echo '<br>';
echo 'new is: '.session_id();
```

?>

Comment: the second one return 2 same session id

Comment: Hello, It would be nice to select an answer so this question can be closed :)

Answer (score 0):

Place

```
session_unset();
```

above session_destroy(); or remove session_unset(); completely. As you are destroying the session.

Try this code:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $oldSessionId ='Old session ID is: ' . session_id() . '<br />';
   echo $oldSessionId;
   session_destroy();
   session_start();
   session_regenerate_id(true);
   echo 'New session ID is: ' . session_id();     
?>
```

You can also add in the following code after session_destroy() if you wish

```
setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: What is wrong with my answer? If you voted it down please explain why to help improve.

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
$old='old is: '.session_id();
session_destroy();
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);
echo $old;
echo '<br>';
echo 'new is: '.session_id();
```

Answer (score -1):

You should destroy session first. Try this:

```
session_destroy();
session_unset();
setcookie(session_name(), null, 0, "/");
```