# PHP custom session ID, optimized version

Tags: php, session

I want to implement a PHP custom session ID, while avoiding calling `session_start()` more than necessary.

Basically, one simple algorithm is

```
session_start();
if ( ! isset( $_SESSION['MyStuff'] )) {
  session_write_close();
  session_id( generate_my_id() );
  session_start();
}

$_SESSION['MyStuff'] = some stuff...;
```

In case the session expired or didn't exist in the first place, the first `session_start()` will create its own ID and send a cookie to the browser. Then the session is ended, and another one is created, with another cookie sending (plus the overhead of creating and closing a session file).

Another solution would be to test if a PHPSESSID cookie exists, and its value having the format according to the - home cooked - generate_my_id() function - then test again if the $_SESSION value. But if the session expired (no $_SESSION['MyStuff']), again, a non-necessary `session_start()` will have been called.

So the question is, based on my observations, actually two questions

- is there a way to specify how PHP should create the session ID (doesn't seem to be possible), before calling `session_start()`?
- is there a way to check if `session_start()` will have to create a new session, or will just use the one available server side? (that would eliminate its first call)

Any good alternative is welcome.

**Edit**

Clarification about what is a custom id.

The session ID is the string key used by PHP to retrieve a session on the server, each user having a different key. That key is usually stored in a cookie, then the browser sends that cookie with its requests to the server / PHP to "connect" to the session.
PHP sets the session ID key automatically, based on MD5(user-and-time-related-data) or SHA1(same-related-data), based on settings. Thus, the session ID is either a MD5 or a SHA1 key - hopefully unique.

A custom ID is a key created manually by the programmer (me), bypassing the md5/sha1 creation.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/a/12799253/984422

Comment: @W Thanks but I don't see where it does

Comment: Hi @ring0 how about this? https://gist.github.com/3898302

Comment: @W This is basically one of the answers below, that doesn't work because a) no custom id, b) `session_id()` result is meaningless  until `session_start()` has been called

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, from 5.3 onwards you can specify the hash algorithm with [`session.hash_function`](http://sg3.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-function) when a session id gets generated; using your own hash algorithm is not recommended, especially since the ones that come with hash are extensively tested for spread, speed, collisions, etc.
2. Since cookies are typically used to perpetuate sessions, you can use that information to determine whether `session_start()` will create a new session or not.

The following illustrates a way to minimize the number of `session_start()` statements you need; it's deduced from existing code (which is OO):

```
do {
    // discover session by cookie
    if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
        session_start();
        // validate session contents
        if (!isset($_SESSION['MyStuff'])) {
            // destroy session and regenerate id
            session_destroy();
            session_regenerate_id(true); // skip this if you generate your own
        } else {
            // validation passed, no need to populate
            break;
        }
    }
    // populate new session
    // you can use session_id($your_id) here
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['MyStuff'] = 'foobar';
} while (false);
```

The strange `do { } while` loop is just a glorified `goto` so that you can skip the second `session_start()` if the current session is valid.

Comment: Is my question(s) that unclear :-) 1. If the cookie doesn't exist, you don't create a custom ID, plus 2. if it exists you call 2 session_start() anyway - since session_regenerate_id() / which actually should be `session_id ( MyCustomID )` since s_regenerate_id doesn't allow a custom creation / would run another session_start(). Please read again the question.

Comment: @ring0 You can just add `session_id()` near the `//populate new session` position and remove `session_regenerate_id()` - it's not that far off; btw, why is there a need to generate ids yourself?

Comment: There is a need of a custom ID based on what we want to achieve - sorry this is not the subject here. Your solution still requires two `session_start()` when session expired (if there is no cookie, we're back to my algorithm).

Comment: @ring0 It only requires two `session_start()` if a cookie is set but the session doesn't validate; I don't see how that could be avoided.

Comment: This is the purpose of this question :-) Either force `session_start()` to use a specific algo (without rewriting the C code!) to generate an ID, or have a way to detect if any session is available server side without having to call `session_start()` beforehand.

Comment: @ring0 You know that you can change the algorithm since 5.3 right? http://sg3.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-function

Comment: These are all hash algorithms - not custom (defined by us) ones.

Comment: @ring0 Perhaps I'm missing something; why would you choose your own hash algorithm over an established one? How would your algorithm be better than, for instance, `sha256` coupled with data from `/dev/urandom`?

Comment: *better* in terms of what? md5 was criticized for collision risks, and weakness compared to sha1. This is not the question. I don't want to enter into details regarding our strategy, but some information is added to the key itself that is used via load balancers, and processors, and that will have an impact on the session file names. Optimization and organization. The question is really the 2 points I mentioned, to which I was hoping a PHP solution exists. I may create a module if it really needs to be implemented as is, to save a few ms...

Comment: Updated the answer, I doubt the additional start() can be avoided if a cookie is pointing to a missing or wrong session. Wouldn't mind to be proven wrong of course.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but check the **[changelog for PHP v5.5.1](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.5.1)**

It refers a new interface called SessionIdInterface which only method is create_sid, although it's still undocumented.

```
interface SessionIdInterface  {
    public function create_sid ();
}
```